# TreeListView programmatically expand node after adding child

Tags: c#, objectlistview, treelistview

I use this code to add a child to a BrightIdeasSoftware TreeListView node:

```
var br = treeListView1.TreeModel.GetBranch(treeListView1.SelectedObject);
((Node)br.Model).Children.Add(new Node(...));
treeListView1.RefreshObject(br.Model);
```

However, when I try to expand the branch after the above code:

```
br.Expand();
```

I get the following error:

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater
>   than the number of elements from index to the end of the source
>   collection.

Any help with this error?

Comment: What version of ObjectListView are you using? v2.7 sometimes had problems rebuilding children, if there was only one child.

Comment: Branch is really an internal class, and it just confuses your code here. It would be simpler to just use var node = (Node)treeListView.SelectedObject;

Comment: @Grammarian I use 2.8.1. This didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
treeListView1.Expand(br.Model);
```